# Are astronomers still using photomultiplier tubes for optical photometry?

Tags: observational-astronomy, photometry, instruments, time-domain-astronomy, eclipsing-star-systems

In [Time domain astronomy and fastest eclipsing binary ZTF J1539+5027 (+20 mag, 6.91 minutes) How to measure it's minimum brightness?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/43435/7982) I've written

> A logarithmic magnitude scale might tend to show *just how deep* but noting that the minimum is dimmer than -21.5 mag and probably lasts only a tiny fraction of the orbital period (i.e. a few seconds) makes a good measurement of the minimum quite a challenge.
>
> It seems to me like this might be a situation where a photomultiplier tube and photon counting might be competitive with photometry based on CCD imaging and clever readout schemes.

This has lead me to wonder more broadly:

**Question:** Are astronomers still using photomultiplier tubes for optical photometry?

These include position-sensitive PMTs but excludes other electron multiplication devices like channel plates and image intensifiers. I'm asking about vacuum tubes with one photocathode, a series of dynodes, and an anode where the multiplied photocurrent can be read out either as a DC average level for higher fluxes (possibly using lock-in techniques) or shaped pulse counting for low flux rates.

Comment: companion question: [Time domain astronomy and fastest eclipsing binary ZTF J1539+5027 (+20 mag, 6.91 minutes) How to measure it's minimum brightness?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/43435/7982)

Comment: I suspect the answer is something like "Yes, in cases where they're using a small telescope with an old instrument that's never been upgraded but is still working".

Comment: For example, [this recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.03972) mentions data taken with the [Tennessee State University 0.4m T3 Automated Photometric Telescope](http://schwab.tsuniv.edu/t3.html), which uses a PMT, from 1997-2019.

Comment: @PeterErwin for [time-structure of optical signals from pulsars](https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.2580) it seems that avalanche photodiodes are now preferred? I guess that's not really photometry though.

Comment: @PeterErwin yes I see what you mean (re. T3)

Comment: How is that not photometry?

Comment: Here's a more recent paper (["Development of an optical photon-counting imager with a monolithic Geiger APD array"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.11907)) suggesting that avalanche photodiodes are indeed preferred.

Comment: @PeterErwin re "How is that not photometry?" oh those are actual light curves, so it is. When I used to use PMTs to make time histograms they were just event-counting (think time of flight of nuclear particles). Old habits die hard.

Comment: PMTs and avalanche photodiodes are often used for the exposure meters of high precision spectrographs used for planet finding via radial velocity see e.g. [this paper](https://www2.keck.hawaii.edu/inst/hires/exposure_meter.pdf) comparing 3 systems and [ESO's HARPS](https://www.eso.org/sci/facilities/lasilla/instruments/harps/inst/gallery.html#misc) (search the gallery for 'exposure meter')

Comment: @astrosnapper without an answer or an upvote this question will eventually disappear via the [roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359901/303080) and even a bounty can't offer more than temporary protection. Would you consider adding a short answer based on your comment? *Thanks!*

Comment: @astrosnapper oh I was wrong, no roomba-ing :-)